# Header and Footer load first

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js

Why the header and footer loaded first and the middle content load after a delay. Here is my code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <nuxt />
    <upper-footer />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: How/Where did you see loading process?

Comment: ok, but i can't see source... The reason may be async action or...  The reasons can be many

Comment: Because they surely do less, if nothing at all.

Comment: @BillalBegueradj can we wait for content to load then load the header and footer components?

Comment: For sure you can easily do that, it is called conditional rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.vue I removed `<no-ssr></no-ssr>` and it is fixed.

Before:

```
<template>
<no-ssr>
My Content
</no-ssr>
</template>
```

After:

```
<template>
My Content
</template>
```